# How to make laravel display grouped values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm developing a question answer app using laravel, I want to display all answers under each question for that particular question. The problem I'm facing is I'm unable to alter the view to display answer under the respective question, since there is no way to match ID's in laravel views!

My view code:

```
@section('list-questions-answers')
    <ul>
        @foreach($listQuestions as $q)
            <li><a href="{{url('/questions/'.$q->question_id)}}">{{ $q->question }}</a></li>
            @foreach($listAnswers as $a)
                <ul>
                    <li>{{ $a->answer }}</li>
                </ul>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Answer's model

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\questions','answer_id');
}
public function scopefetchAnswers($query)
{
    return $query->select('answer')->where('people_id','<>',Auth::id())->get();
}
```

Question's model:

```
protected $table='questions';
protected $primaryKey='question_id';
protected $fillable = [
   'question', 'created_at','details'
];
//protected $hidden=['question_id'];
public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value) {}
public function User() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\answers','question_id');
}
public function scopefetchQuestions($query) {
    return $query->select('question','question_id')->where('people_id','=',Auth::id())->get();
}
```

Everything is display on the dashboard.blade.php, which runs on dashboard controller

```
class Dashboard extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $listQuestions=questions::latest('created_at')->fetchQuestions();
        //$listAnswers=answers::groupBy('question_id')->fetchAnswers();
        $listAnswers=answers::fetchAnswers();
        return view('forms.question',compact('listQuestions','listAnswers'));
    }
}
```

Output I'm getting

[image: Current Output]

Ouput I want

[image: Required output]

Answer's table

[image]

How can I achive that output? I'm using Laravel 5.2

Comment: Can you show your questions Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query to fetch questions should be as:

```
$listQuestions= Question::where('people_id', '=', Auth::id())
                            ->with(['answers' => function($q) {
                                $q->where('people_id', '<>' ,Auth::id());
                             }])
                            ->get();
```

And your view file should be as:

```
section('list-questions-answers')
    <ul>
        @foreach($listQuestions as $q)
            <li><a href="{{url('/questions/'.$q->question_id)}}">{{ $q->question }}</a></li>
            @foreach($q->answers as $a)
                <ul>
                    <li>{{ $a->answer }}</li>
                </ul>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Comment: its throwing a syntax error `syntax error, unexpected '}'`

Comment: In you first code above near `Auth::id())
                             }])
                            ->get()`

Comment: no! u forgot `->get();` after `Auth:id())` , works now!

Comment: There is no need to add `get()` method in `with()` closure. Here we are chaining the queries whereas `get()` will fetch the data from the database. I suggest you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) thoroughly.

Comment: Well, it only runs if I add the get(), else it throws an error!

Comment: I am not sure why its happening but `get()` used when your query is complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126993/discussion-between-jaskaran-singh-puri-and-amit-gupta).